# JS Score array: How to add a number to the score array and knock out lower numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to research in order to create a scoreboard for my game. I did find an article but it was a bit complicated.

So I started from scratch:

1. create an empty array
2. populate `<ol>` tags that's already in HTML with `<li>` in JS
3. get a new score after game over
4. add it to the top of the list
5. when the list has some numbers, to compare the new score to the scoreboard list, to filter through the array list and splice in the new score if it's higher than the number
6. return new array with 10 items

I already did #1 to #3.

I'm working on #5 and I need some help.

Here is my code:

```js
let scoreArr = [24, 22, 19, 16, 15, 13, 10, 7, 6, 3];
let newScore = 8;
console.log(scoreArr);

for (let i = 0; i < scoreArr.length; i++) {
  if (newScore > scoreArr[i]) {
    return scoreArr.splice(i, 0, newScore);
    break;
  }
}
console.log(scoreArr);
```

I couldn't get it to work in codepen: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/rNNdRXO?editors=0001;

Comment: would it be possible to have duplicate scores in this system?

Comment: are you trying to remove the last one or the smaller one? and do you intend to keep the list in a bigger to smaller order or can it start getting randomised by always inserting at the top?

Comment: @rule - The last one = the smallest one, because of the way the values are being inserted. *"and do you intend to keep the list in a bigger to smaller order"* That seems to be the intention. That's certainly what the code does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right, was confused by explanation itself and didnt pay enough attention to the code itself, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're inserting at the beginning of the array and you want to get rid of entries at the end, you can just assign to `length`:

```
scoreArr.splice(i, 0, newScore);
scoreArr.length = Math.min(scoreArr.length, 10); // Where 10 is the max scores you want to keep
break;
```

Assigning a lower value to the `length` of an array removes entries from the end. I'm using `Math.min` there so that you don't assign 10 when the array has fewer than 10 entries in it.

I don't know why you were using `return` on the `splice` line (it would always return an empty array, because you aren't removing any entries with `splice`), so I've left it off.

---

Note that your logic will never add a lower score to the array than the scores that are there, even if there's room. To do that, `push` after the loop if there's room:

```js
function example(newScore) {
  let scoreArr = [24, 22, 19, 16, 15, 13, 10, 7, 6];

  for (let i = 0; i < scoreArr.length; i++) {
    if (newScore > scoreArr[i]) {
      // Inserting within the list
      scoreArr.splice(i, 0, newScore);
      scoreArr.length = Math.min(scoreArr.length, 10);
      return scoreArr;
    }
  }
  if (scoreArr.length < 10) {
    // Adding to the end
    scoreArr.push(newScore);
  }
  return scoreArr;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(example(3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(example(8)));
```

Comment: If I create an empty array like this: `let scores = new Array(10);
for(let i=0; i<scores.length;i++){scores[i] = "";}` and use it as the array in place of scoreArr. Would this be fine?

Comment: @KristinaBressler - Create it like this: `let scores = [];` and don't fill it in. Or if you prefer to have it be fixed size, fill it with zeros: `let scores = Array.fill(Array(10), 0);` If you know the array is fixed size, the code above can be shorter as well: `--scores.length; let index = scores.findIndex(score => score < newScore); if (index === -1) { index = scores.length; } scores.splice(index, 0, newScore);`

Comment: I tried `let scores = Array.fill(Array(10), 0);` in my code and I got an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Array.fill is not a function`

Comment: Anyway, I think I'll prefer to have the list blank until the gamer fill it in with new score

Comment: @KristinaBressler - That's what I'd do. And sorry, it would be `let scores = Array(10).fill(0);` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to have duplicates in this system, you could simply do this:

```
function updateScore(scoreArr,newScore){
    return [...scoreArr, newScore].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 10);
}
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this. I tend not to think this way, because of all the temporary objects that get created, but for the use case described *that just doesn't matter* and this is short and easy to understand (once you know the parts involved).

Comment: That's a good question. However, in my case, when I'm creating a scoreboard with list of scores, the way my code is set up is that for loop will loop the array and stop at the duplicate and push the new duplicate in the place. Like this: `let scoreArr = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]` with `newScore = 8` will become `[10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6]`